# Question about bosonization method

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory

I have a question about bosonization method used in 1D system.  Generally the bosonized field is assume to the following form
\begin{equation}
\psi = e^{i\phi}, \quad \phi = \phi^\dagger
\end{equation}
On the Haldane's method, however, the bosonized field is assumed to take the following slightly different form
\begin{equation}
\psi = \sqrt{\rho} e^{i\phi}, \quad \rho = \rho_0 + \Pi
\end{equation}
where $\Pi$ and $\phi$ are conjugate pair. My question is that why these two methods are totally different but both of them are widely used in literatures.  How can I understand that these two methods are equivalent?

Maybe these two methods are identical, but this is a very strong claim and need justification.